# find function does not display desired string

Tags: python, list, find

Hey so I am doing a project that is supposed to be a word search calculator. The word search is a 10x10 list of characters turned into rows of characters. I did a .find function for my check forward, however it is not working correctly. I will provide my get puzzle function, my check forward and what the output should be (ignore the format of the puzzle for output).

```
def input_puzzle():
print("Puzzle:\n")
puzzle_input = input()
puzzle_list = []
for i in range(10):
    row = ""
    for j in range(10):
        row += puzzle_input[i*10 + j]
    puzzle_list.append(row)
return puzzle_list



def check_forward(puzzle_list, word, direction):
for row in range(len(puzzle_list)):
    row_string = puzzle_list[row]
    finder = row_string.find(word)
    if finder > 0:
        print(word + ":" + direction + "row:" + row, "column:", finder) # finder is the indeci in row #+ means right after and comma means space
        return True
    else:
        print(word + ": word not found")
        return False


"""
Puzzle:
WAQHGTTWEE
CBMIVQQELS
APXWKWIIIL
LDELFXPIPV
PONDTMVAMN
OEDSOYQGOB
LGQCKGMMCT
YCSLOAPUZM
XVDMGSXCYZ
UUIUNIXFNU

UNIX: (FORWARD) row: 9 column: 3
"""
```

Comment: If you represent your puzzle as a list of strings, you can use `str.find()` to do the hard work. To search for vertical words, transpose your data into columnwise strings.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works

```
def input_puzzle():
    print("Puzzle:\n")
    puzzle_input = input()
    puzzle_input = puzzle_input.strip()
    puzzle_list = []
    for i in range(10):
        row = ""
        for j in range(10):
            row += puzzle_input[i*11 + j]
        puzzle_list.append(row)
    return puzzle_list



def check_forward(puzzle_list, word, direction):
    for row in range(len(puzzle_list)):
        row_string = puzzle_list[row]
        finder = row_string.find(word)
        if finder > 0:
            print("{}: ({}) row: {} column: {}".format(word, direction, str(row), str(finder)))
            return True
        else:
            continue
    print(word + ": word not found")
            
print(check_forward(input_puzzle(), 'UNIX', 'FORWARD'))
# UNIX: (FORWARD) row: 9 column: 3
```